# get the ASIN number from amazon URL

Tags: ruby, regex, amazon-web-services

Given a amazon product URL, which can either be

```
http://amazon.com/gp/product/ASIN/*
http://amazon.com/*/dp/ASIN/*
http://amazon.com/dp/ASIN/*
```

how do i scrap the ASIN number from the URL in Ruby ? I am not good at writing regular expressions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use should find match by:

```
scan(/https?:\/\/(?:www\.|)amazon\.com\/(?:gp\/product|[^\/]+\/dp|dp)\/([^\/]+)/)
```

Comment: I still doesn't extract the ASIN from the URL

Comment: it still doesn't work if the Url is 

http://www.amazon.com/Fitbit-Wireless-Activity-Sleep-Tracker/dp/B005PUONIK/ref=pd_cp_e_3 
which is the 2nd case in the posted question

Comment: You need [s] after http as the URL can be https

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to do a lot of URL parsing, I'd recommend looking at the [Addressable::URI](http://addressable.rubyforge.org/api/Addressable/URI.html) gem. It will make it a lot easier to maintain than parsing URLs with regex. Take a look at its [Template](http://addressable.rubyforge.org/api/Addressable/Template.html) module too, which is designed just for this purpose.

Look at the examples on the main [Addressable](http://addressable.rubyforge.org/api/) page for more information.

You could also use Ruby's built-in URI module, to get the path using `path`, along with a simple string split and some logic to look at which element has the "`dp`" and then take the next element in the array or "`gp`" and take the second following element.